# Outliers in EDA - With or without?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, correlation, outliers, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm trying to carry out my first EDA on a Student Performance dataset. The dataset has 395 samples and consists of 33 attributes. After drawing the boxplots and doing some tests I detected outliers in 10 of those attributes, ranging from very small percentages (0.3%) to higher ones (up to 21%). In some columns, whether outliers are indeed outliers is a bit subjective (eg students not showing up on exams and receiving grade 0) but let's ignore those.

My main concern is this:

**I want to check pairwise associations between my variables. Should I include outliers when doing this or not?**

---

I've already written my question but I'll include some more info in case it helps.

Initially, I decided to include the outliers in the tests. This is the strategy I followed:

1. I found which variables follow (approximately) the normal distribution. No such variable was found, so I proceeded with non-parametric tests for the pairwise assocations.
2. I used Spearman's rank correlation coefficient for numerical variable pairs, since Speraman is insensitive to outliers.
3. For categorical pairs, I used Monte Carlo chi-squared.
4. For binary and numeric pairs I used Shapiro to determine if the numeric variable follows a normal distribution in each of the two levels of the binary variable. Shapiro showed that no variable follows the normal distribution in any binary level, so I proceeded with the Mann - Whitney U test.
5. For nominal and numeric pairs, I used ANOVA followed by Shapiro to verify normality of residuals.

I've been studying several EDA examples to get the grasp of the EDA steps but it seems like everyone has their own approach. Most do not even use these statistical tests. Plots and correlation matrices are as far as they go with pairwise associations. Am I making this too complicated?

Comment: (1) Welcome to CV, Christina.  It isn't usually appropriate or useful to characterize 21% of the values of a variable as "outliers".  This suggests you might not be doing EDA, but instead are applying some kind of generic screening procedure.  Could you be more specific about what you mean by an "outlier"? (2) It is unusual to be testing variables for Normality during EDA and ordinarily it's inappropriate to be making analytic decisions based on passing those tests or not.  (3) We lack any information about *why* you are doing this.  Could you explain?

Comment: @whuber 1)I found the percentage of outliers by making a boxplot of each variable in R. To my understanding, boxplot uses IQR to identify the outliers.2)I'm new to the EDA procedure so I could be totally wrong here. But aren't pairwise associations considered part of the "exploring"? Regardless, the guidelines I have demand normality tests before deciding which test will be used.3)It's a post-graduate assignment. Eda is the first part and making a model to predict grades is the second. I'm specifically asked to explore pairwise associations in the first part so I kind of have to dig into that.

Comment: @whuber is entirely correct, but it is probably worth adding that the 'outliers' that are sometimes automatically plotted with boxplots are only 'outliers' in that they are at the edges of the data. They are not usually 'outliers' in the sense of being unrepresentatively or erroneously wild. It would be rare that omission of the boxplot outliers would be helpful in preliminary data analysis.

Comment: Re your guidelines about normality tests: please take a look at [some of our threads about this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normality+test+useless).